# Delphi XE8 - Share variables between threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe8

I would like to know if it's possible to have this situation:

1) have a master thread with some variables.

2) this thread would have to create 2 sub-threads and this threads should be able to read the variables of the master thread.

3) I would like to create different master threads (with the sub-threads).

Is this even possible?

I tried this so far, but it does not work (Check "procedure TSubThread.Execute;" ):

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TMainThread = class(TThread)
  private
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    TestVar1: integer;
  end;

  TSubThread = class(TMainThread)
  private
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
  end;

  TfMain = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    function RunThread(trTestVar1: integer): TMainThread;
    procedure ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);

    function RunSubThread: TSubThread;
    procedure SubThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  fMain: TfMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                               MAINTHREAD
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function TfMain.RunThread(trTestVar1: integer): TMainThread;
var CalcThread : TMainThread;
begin
  CalcThread := TMainThread.Create(true);
  CalcThread.TestVar1 := trTestVar1;
  CalcThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
  CalcThread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
  CalcThread.Start;
  Result := CalcThread;

  // Here I start the SUB-THREAD
  RunSubThread;
end;

procedure TfMain.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
//
end;

procedure TMainThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
end;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                               SUBTHREAD
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function TfMain.RunSubThread: TSubThread;
var SubThread : TSubThread;
begin
  SubThread := TSubThread.Create(true);
  SubThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
  SubThread.OnTerminate := SubThreadTerminated;
  SubThread.Start;
  Result := SubThread;
end;

procedure TfMain.SubThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //
end;

procedure TSubThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;

  // Here the value of TestVar1 is always 0
end;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                               MAIN THREAD
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

procedure TfMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // I start the first "Main Thread"
  RunThread(1);

  // I start the second "Main Thread"
  RunThread(2);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Sharing variables between threads is trivial to do. You just make them visible, just as you would share variables between objects. Of course, now you have to deal with data races. As a general rule, sharing is something that you want to minimise. If possible, have no sharing at all and then you have no contention.

Comment: You call our attention to `TSubThread.Execute`, where a comment says that `TestVar1` is always 0. Nothing in this code assigns `TestVar1`, so the only value it will ever have is the value it gets when its enclosing object is created, which is 0. What other value would you expect it to have, in `TSubThread.Execute` or elsewhere?

Comment: I was hoping that the value i pass inside RunThread(1) and RunThread(2) would set that variable with 1 and 2. It was just a test, which it does not work...and I was hoping for some advice..

Comment: If you don't know the basics of Pascal, moving on to threads is a bit like trying to drive in an Indy 500 race when you just got your beginner's license. Slow down there, junior.

Comment: Warren, I don't know what you mean..Christian (below) understood the question and also solved it..did you just write here to offend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not correct to let the SubThread inherit from the MainThread and then expect to get the test value.

I think it is much better to let the SubThread hold a reference to your Main Thread, and then you end up with this:

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TMainThread = class(TThread)
  private
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    TestVar1: integer;
  end;

  TSubThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FMainThread : TMainThread;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
  end;

  TfMain = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    function RunThread(trTestVar1: integer): TMainThread;
    procedure ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);

    function RunSubThread(MainThread : TMainThread): TSubThread;
    procedure SubThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  fMain: TfMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                               MAINTHREAD
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function TfMain.RunThread(trTestVar1: integer): TMainThread;
var CalcThread : TMainThread;
begin
  CalcThread := TMainThread.Create(true);
  CalcThread.TestVar1 := trTestVar1;
  CalcThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
  CalcThread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
  CalcThread.Start;
  Result := CalcThread;

  // Here I start the SUB-THREAD
  RunSubThread(CalcThread);
end;

procedure TfMain.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
//
end;

procedure TMainThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
end;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                               SUBTHREAD
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function TfMain.RunSubThread(MainThread : TMainThread): TSubThread;
var SubThread : TSubThread;
begin
  SubThread := TSubThread.Create(true);
  SubThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
  SubThread.FMainThread := MainThread;
  SubThread.OnTerminate := SubThreadTerminated;
  SubThread.Start;
  Result := SubThread;
end;

procedure TfMain.SubThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //
end;

procedure TSubThread.Execute;
var
  VarCopy : Integer;
begin
  inherited;

  VarCopy := self.FMainThread.TestVar1;

  // Here the value of TestVar1 is always 0
end;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                               MAIN THREAD
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

procedure TfMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // I start the first "Main Thread"
  RunThread(1);

  // I start the second "Main Thread"
  RunThread(2);
end;

end.
```

Comment: WOOOW! that worked!!! that's just what i needed!! do you think it's safe to use it like this?

Comment: One last question, if I change the value of TestVar1 from the main-thread, will the sub-thread see the change?

Comment: Perfect. The further success depends very much on what kind of which data structures you are using. A single simple integer is OK. But if you need to access a record of results in an array or similar it will soon be necessary to use TCriticalSection or InterlockedDecrement etc. to ensure data consistency. And yes, the sub-thread will "see" the change next time is checks the variable.

Comment: Amazing! I actually am going to use a boolean and a varchar...so I should be ok, but why with arrays I would have problems? I just have one sub-thread for each main-thread, where is the consistency problem?

Comment: If the main thread is in the process of updating the array with a new result, and there is no locking mechanism for this array, there is nothing to prevent the OS from handing over control to the subtask that will also read the same array. This can lead to "half" results. If the length of the array is changed during update strange access violations will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to share variables among multiple threads. It's nearly automatic. If a variable's scope allows it to be referenced, then it will be accessible by whatever thread executes the code.

In the code provided, none of the threads have any way of referring to each other. In particular, the subthread has no reference to any instance of `TMainThread`, and so it won't be able to access the `TestVar1` member of any such thread.

Comment: I don't know if it's correct (probably not) but creating the sub-thread with the main thread class ( TSubThread = class(TMainThread)) allows me to see the variable of the mainthread from the subthread.

Comment: the problem is that the 1st time i run the main thread the variable is 1 but the second time is 2. I would need these 2 values to change in the subthreads, but it's always 0

Comment: Each time you call `RunMainThread`, you create an instance of `TMainThread`, and then you call `RunSubThread`, which creates an instance of `TSubThread`. Since `TSubThread` is a descendant of `TMainThread`, you actually have *two* `TMainThread` instances. The first one, where you assigned `TestVar` from `trTestVar`, and the second one, which is really a `TSubThread` instances, where you didn't set `TestVar1` at all. Ultimately, you end up with *four* thread instances, and *each* one has a separate `TestVar1` member variable. That's not sharing.